# Show DetailView from UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have an app in portrait, in my View Controller (`UIViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`) there is a table (`UITableView`) that only occupies half the screen. 
I set the delegate and datasource of my table view to my view controller.

Now, I would like to show a detail view when i select any cell of my table. Here is what I tried but nothing appears:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"SELECTED");

//ChangeView

DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
dvController = nil;

}
```

Any idea? Is this solution better than a popup solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should check your tableview in nib file it datasource and delegate is connected or not?
just connect both with file owner.

and if you are using uiview controller then use present model view controller not push modelview controller.

```
DetailViewController *dvc=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Now, delegate and datasource are connected. how use present model view controller?

Comment: First check after connecting delegate and datasource your table is working or not?if work then its ok with puch notification or if not working then try with present modelviewcontroller.I will show code for that.first try that only.

Comment: If your View Coming from down then why You are using navigationController just use viewcontroller only.

Answer (score 2):

Put `[NSBundle mainBundle]` in place of nil. Hope it helps. Tell me what happens!
Also replace `dvController=nil;` with `[dvController release];`

**EDIT:**
Replace ur init function with this one:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{ 
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
return self;
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but nothing. I use ARC and i can not use "release".

Comment: mmm. OK. Is init Function present in ur Controller which u r pushing?

Comment: There is this the classic initWithNibName: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: Nothing, maybe i have not declared the navigation controller in viewController, i have insert the navigation controller in nib file also. maybe the problem is this one.

Comment: I was assuming that u r clear with those things! Tell me if that solves ur problem

Answer (score 1):

initialize navigation controller. becauze some time it is due to ui component which has not initialized. but remember that you may have to face some other UI issues

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is really called or not when you select a table cell (of not, your delegate may not be set correctly), then if

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

returns nil or something meaningful with a debugger, trying to close in on the problem. Also, @M.A.Khan was right, you should remove

```
dvController = nil;
```

and replace it with

```
[dvController release];
```

giving up the reference in your main view.

**Edit:**
Your code asumes that beneath your UIViewController, there is a UINavigationController because you're using `[self.navigationController pushViewController]`. If there isn't, no wonder your view does not get pushed onto something that doesn't exist.

Comment: There in not a UINavigationController. Probably this is the problem. I try to do something.

Comment: It's a simple matter of using an UINavigationController to your app and adding your UIViewController as rootController onto it when you launch the app. Then your code will work.

Comment: Don't work. I don't know. The DetailViewController is initialized but nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

is the viewcontroller with tableview in a navigationcontroller?if not then first you have to create a navigationcontroller with the current viewcontroller as the rootviewcontroller.then try this code u are using now

Comment: @Byteros in your comment to zero0cool u are saying there is no navigationcontroller....???? contradictions?

Comment: Yes, before. Now is in. I have tied the solution of @zero0cool.